# Sympify Error when finding distance between 2 coordinates in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with 4 columns representing the X and Y coordinates of 2 points, alpha and beta. I want to return the euclidian distance between alpha and beta.

This is my data frame:

```
   alpha_x       alpha_y        beta_x        beta_y
0  3.770047e+06 -1.933178e+07  3.771670e+06 -1.932118e+07
1  3.764890e+06 -1.927422e+07  3.759280e+06 -1.922667e+07
2  3.758185e+06 -1.922737e+07  3.758199e+06 -1.922815e+07
3  3.758748e+06 -1.923129e+07  3.758748e+06 -1.923129e+07
4  3.769639e+06 -1.934297e+07  3.770114e+06 -1.933611e+07
```

You can load it with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

data =[[3770047.175941625, -19331776.34887237, 3771670.214117389, -19321175.08603543], 
       [3764889.7439331706, -19274223.583930705, 3759280.354792099, -19226669.81098408], 
       [3758184.9710026933, -19227374.77475073, 3758199.442536497, -19228148.049991384], 
       [3758748.247626108, -19231287.595948454, 3758748.247626108, -19231287.595948454], 
       [3769638.633410415, -19342974.05279793, 3770113.9676361005, -19336111.98073229]
       ]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['alpha_x', 'alpha_y', 'beta_x', 'beta_y'])
```

I tried creating a function to run the respective coordinates for each row through a Pythagoras equation and return it in a newly created 5th column [Distance]

```
def dist(row):
    h = abs(dataframe['alpha_x']- dataframe['beta_x'])
    v = abs(dataframe['alpha_y']- dataframe['beta_y'])
    d = sqrt((h**2) + (v**2))
    return d

dataframe["distance"] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: dist(row), axis = 1)
```

However, the column is not created in my df and I am returned with a SympifyError instead:

```
SympifyError: SympifyError: 0    1.150210e+08
1    2.292827e+09
2    5.981640e+05
3    0.000000e+00
4    4.731398e+07
dtype: float64
```

I appreciate if anyone can guide me on what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change function with replace `dataframe` to `row` for processes by rows:

```
def dist(row):
    h = abs(row['alpha_x']- row['beta_x'])
    v = abs(row['alpha_y']- row['beta_y'])
    d = np.sqrt((h**2) + (v**2))
    return d

dataframe["distance"] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: dist(row), axis = 1)
```

Better solution with no loops:

```
h = (dataframe['alpha_x'] - dataframe['beta_x']).abs()
v = (dataframe['alpha_y'] - dataframe['beta_y']).abs()
dataframe["distance1"]  = np.sqrt((h**2) + (v**2))
```

---

```
print (dataframe)
        alpha_x       alpha_y        beta_x        beta_y      distance  \
0  3.770047e+06 -1.933178e+07  3.771670e+06 -1.932118e+07  10724.785623   
1  3.764890e+06 -1.927422e+07  3.759280e+06 -1.922667e+07  47883.468630   
2  3.758185e+06 -1.922737e+07  3.758199e+06 -1.922815e+07    773.410643   
3  3.758748e+06 -1.923129e+07  3.758748e+06 -1.923129e+07      0.000000   
4  3.769639e+06 -1.934297e+07  3.770114e+06 -1.933611e+07   6878.515513   

      distance1  
0  10724.785623  
1  47883.468630  
2    773.410643  
3      0.000000  
4   6878.515513
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem and I see my mistake.